# jquery loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my loop. I want to print 7 li tag and 5 ul tags. This is my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++) {
            $("#calendar").append("<ul></ul>");

        for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {

            $("#calendar ul").append("<li></li>").addClass("days");
            $("#calendar ul li").addClass("day");

            count = count + 1;
        };
    };
```

but the result is quite different from the expectation. There are 35, 28, 21, 14 and 7 li tags in each consecutive loop. I understand why it is so. The li tags are appended to all the ul's in the #calendar div.

Now, what is the proper way to appended li to the ul tags without the repeatation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite you code like below,

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++) {
  var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo("#calendar").addClass("days");
  for(var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
      $("<li>").appendTo(ul).addClass("day");
      count = count + 1;
  };
};
```

You are using a generic selector `$("#something ul")`, that will select all the `UL` elements inside of that `div`. So you have to collect the newly generated `ul` in a variable and use it for further manipulations.

Recent edit: inspired from APJhony's code.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

It is because `$("#calendar ul")` will select all the `ul` elements in `calendar` including the previously added one's.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo('#calendar').addClass('days');
  for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
    $("<li></li>", {
      'class': 'day'
    }).appendTo($ul);
  };
};
```

```css
.days {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.day {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

---

You can also try

```js
var $ul = $(new Array(6).join('<ul class="days"></ul>')).appendTo('#calendar');
$ul.append(new Array(8).join('<li class="day"></li>'));
```

```css
.days {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.day {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The part `$("#calendar ul").append("<li></li>").addClass("days");` will append a `li` to all existing `ul`'s in the calendar element.

Best to do is to save a reference to the `ul` you want to append the `li`'s to, and do this in the first loop. Then, in the second loop, add the li's.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++) {
  var $ul = $('<ul/>', { class: 'days'} );

  for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
    var $li = $('<li/>', { class: 'day', text: 'li test' });

    $ul.append($li);
  };

  $('#calendar').append($ul);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7fkw641/

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++) {
        $("#calendar").append("<ul></ul>");
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        $("#calendar ul:last-child").append("<li></li>").addClass("days");
        $("#calendar ul:last-child li").addClass("day");
    };
};
```

You can only add `ul:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run `$("#calendar ul").append(...)`, you append data to every single element in the DOM that matches `#calendar ul`. I recommend building up your elements one by one assigning the results of `$(some_html_string)` to variables. This way `ul` will only mean one `<ul>` element at a time. For example:

```
var calendar = $("#calendar");

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    ul.addClass("days");

    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        var li = $("<li></li>");
        li.addClass("day");
        ul.append(li);
        count = count + 1;
    }

    calendar.append(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create dynamically 5 ul's and inside which 7 li's

**Updated Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++) {
        $("#calendar").append("<ul></ul>");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        $("#calendar ul").append("<li></li>").addClass("days");
        $("#calendar ul li").addClass("day"); 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error is here its appending **li** to all the class items every and each time he goes in second loop(starting from first **ul**) to prevent that block it with id (i left the class name assuming it is important to handle css or something).

here is the simple solution

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            $("#calendar").append("<ul class='days' id='"+i+"'></ul>")

        for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {

            $("#calendar #"+i+".days ").append("<li class='day'></li>");

        };
    };
```

[image: output]